# Font Size change KerningAdjustment, why?

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, kerning

**I solved the problem, I created a function where I just pass the value of the spacing I need and the TextField**

```
public static void ChangeSpaceBetweenCharacters(this UITextField textField, float space)
{
   textField.WeakDefaultTextAttributes.SetValueForKey(NSObject.FromObject((nfloat)space), UIStringAttributeKey.KerningAdjustment);

}
```

Best regards,
Rafael Santos

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be caused by the font method you use, I can't make it work with:

```
 UIFont("ArialMT", 13)
```

Instead, you can use :

```
 Font = UIFont.FromName("ArialMT", 13),
```

Or

```
 Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10),
```

I test below sample code and it works for me:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSMutableAttributedString mtText = new NSMutableAttributedString("testTextfield", new UIStringAttributes
    {
        Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10),
        KerningAdjustment = 8.0f

    });

    UITextField textField = new UITextField();
    textField.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10,20,350,50);
    textField.AttributedText = mtText;        

    Add(textField);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think it's a communication problem between VS for Mac and Xcode.

The solution I found was to change the font in Xcode, so it already works.

But thanks anyway.